Geometry Nodes: Delete Specific Instance along a Curve with multiple Instanced Objects

So I'm trying to make a chain by instancing the links along a curve. These links need to be 2 different objects so I'm instancing a collection, which alternates them.
So far so good, but I'd like to be able to delete specific instanced objects.
From a previous question I got how to kinda make a mask that prevents the instance from using that point, but the problem is that it's not deleting that instance, it's deleting the point, so the next point uses the vertical link object instead of the horizontal link again (As if the vertical one had been deleted).
Is there a way to delete specific instances and not the points? If I put the 'Delete geometry' node after the 'Instance on points' node, it just deletes one of the faces from all the instances  instead.
I think one solution would be, instead of instancing the collection, to have one link object instanced on the odd points and the other on the even ones, then just join them together. That way the mask should work, I think. But I don't know how to do that so I'd appreciate it if anyone shows how regardless of whether it's needed for this particular example.
I'm using Blender 3.5.1 if it matters.


Just use a selection input socket instead the delete geometry node:


Is there a way to set this up so you can delete 2 or more instances? I can't connect 2 different nodes to the Selection input

Nvm I found it, it's the Boolean Math node to join the selections
